CPLEX Working Memory
I have an integer program that is memory intensive. When I solve the problem with defaults the best LP relaxation constantly keeps improving even if the extent of improvement is small. But occasionally the process hits the RAM limit and get killed. I tried setting the working memory to half my RAM size and set parameters.mip.strategy.file to 2 so that it saves the branch and bound node information to disk. However, I see no change in the lower bounds (for a minimization problem) as soon as it starts writing things to the disk. Is this expected? Here is a sample output
Nodefile size = 43258.08 MB
 1449544 1051851        cutoff             71.0000       81.7427 4.08e+08   15.13%
 1451098 1054212       78.6300   476       71.0000       81.7427 4.09e+08   15.13%
 1452597 1055824       73.9231   385       71.0000       81.7427 4.10e+08   15.13%
 1454057 1055600       72.1071   433       71.0000       81.7427 4.10e+08   15.13%
 1455470 1057277       77.7467   472       71.0000       81.7427 4.10e+08   15.13%
 1456896 1058662       77.8155   461       71.0000       81.7427 4.11e+08   15.13%
 1458341 1060708       77.6697   453       71.0000       81.7427 4.11e+08   15.13%
 1459864 1061817       72.7683   392       71.0000       81.7427 4.12e+08   15.13%
 1461252 1061447       73.5695   391       71.0000       81.7427 4.11e+08   15.13%
 1462545 1063452        cutoff             71.0000       81.7427 4.12e+08   15.13%
Elapsed time = 6311.79 sec. (9827614.29 ticks, tree = 110040.94 MB, solutions = 14)
Nodefile size = 44478.74 MB
 1463939 1065105       74.2626   417       71.0000       81.7427 4.13e+08   15.13%
 1465352 1065200       77.2853   438       71.0000       81.7427 4.13e+08   15.13%
 1466702 1067141       75.8846   440       71.0000       81.7427 4.13e+08   15.13%
 1468028 1068524       77.2965   470       71.0000       81.7427 4.14e+08   15.13%
 1469951 1069047       77.4076   456       71.0000       81.7427 4.14e+08   15.13%
 1472216 1071555       75.5482   439       71.0000       81.7427 4.15e+08   15.13%
 1474030 1073084       72.7877   413       71.0000       81.7427 4.15e+08   15.13%
 1475591 1074457       78.8004   455       71.0000       81.7427 4.16e+08   15.13%
 1477028 1074242       78.5179   466       71.0000       81.7427 4.16e+08   15.13%
 1478459 1076534       74.6344   433       71.0000       81.7427 4.17e+08   15.13%
Elapsed time = 6434.20 sec. (9980255.36 ticks, tree = 111353.25 MB, solutions = 14)
Nodefile size = 45792.32 MB
 1479839 1077168       77.6324   471       71.0000       81.7427 4.17e+08   15.13%
 1481308 1077807       77.9929   444       71.0000       81.7427 4.17e+08   15.13%
 1482785 1080255       77.7287   456       71.0000       81.7427 4.18e+08   15.13%
 1484194 1079961       79.4435   466       71.0000       81.7427 4.18e+08   15.13%
 1485607 1082595       77.4371   469       71.0000       81.7427 4.19e+08   15.13%
 1487007 1082691       78.7123   446       71.0000       81.7427 4.19e+08   15.13%
 1488415 1085007       79.5992   490       71.0000       81.7427 4.19e+08   15.13%
 1489793 1084549       77.0949   446       71.0000       81.7427 4.19e+08   15.13%
 1491306 1087049       73.9583   399       71.0000       81.7427 4.20e+08   15.13%
 1492752 1087298       73.7246   393       71.0000       81.7427 4.20e+08   15.13%```


Memory use increases with number of threads. due to each thread having its own copy of the B&B tree (or something like that). Have you limited or considered limiting max number of threads? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=threads-parameter

Are you A: asking/implying, that the process of improving the lower-bound stops when using those parameters while it doesn't when not using those parameters or are you B: asking why there is no observable progress on the lower-bound after X time which you never could have observed without memory-saving as it would crash before this happens? The answer to B might be: BnB doesn't do enough pruning for your model and cutting-planes might be better -> different solver-focus, see also: Klotz, Ed, and Alexandra M. Newman. "Practical guidelines for solving difficult mixed integer linear programs."

I'm asking about A. When I remove the parameters that instruct CPLEX to write to a file, it constantly keeps improving the lower bound

Do you mean C: BOTH params together trigger it or D: the file strat alone? D would be more surprising (although i see prubins point). With C i guess cplex turns of some stuff due to the reduced memory available. I would start with cranking up MIP node log display ("the node log adds a line specifying the number of cutting planes added to the problem since the last node log line was displayed") and see when and how those two different configurations diverge. Sadly there are a multitude of reasons for divergence, but maybe there is still some valuable information there.

These are the parameters I'm using                                  problem.parameters.mip.strategy.file.set(2)
problem.parameters.workmem.set(65536)

I will confess that I am speculating here, since I am not privy to the inner workings of CPLEX. This may tie to your node selection strategy, which I assume is not depth-first. When CPLEX needs to move to a new node after backtracking and the tree is entirely in RAM, it is unconstrained in its choice of next node. When the disk storage option is used, CPLEX may give preference to nodes that are in memory over nodes that are on disk (requiring retrieval of a chunk of the disk storage and possibly movement of a chuck of the RAM storage to disk). So if the node with the best current bound is in a chunk of the tree parked on disk, it may be a while before CPLEX gets to it, and in the meantime the best bound cannot change because that node is still sitting out there unaltered.
